# Create a dual function html Url Link?

Tags: javascript, url

**Problem:**

You have a regular set of URL links in a HTML page e.g.:

```
<a href="/foo/bar">Foo Bar</a>
```

You want to create a JavaScript function such that when any HTML links are clicked, instead of the client's browser navigating to that new URL "/foo/bar" a JavaScript function is executed instead *(**e.g**. this may for example make an Ajaxian call and load the HTML data without the need to reload the page)*.

However if the JavaScript is **disabled** OR a **spider** crawls the site, the UTL links are maintained gracefully.

Is this possible? Does it already exist? What's the usual approach?

**EDIT 1:**

These are some great answers!

Just a follow on question:

If the user clicks on the back button OR forward button, this would naturally break (as in it would go back to the last physical page it was on as opposed to one that was loaded).

Is there any way (cross browser) to maintain the back/forward buttons?

(e.g create an array of links clicked and over ride the browser buttons and use the array to navigate)?

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function your_function() {
        alert('clicked!');
    }
</script>

<a onclick="your_function();" href="/foo/bar">Foo Bar</a>
```

If Javascript is off, the link behaves normally.

In this case, unless `your_function()` does not return false, the link will be followed when clicked as well.

To prevent this, either make `your_function()` return false, or add `return false;` just after the function call in your onclick attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function your_function() {
        alert('clicked!');
        return false;
    }
</script>

<a onclick="your_function();" href="/foo/bar">Foo Bar</a>
```

Or:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function your_function() {
        alert('clicked!');
    }
</script>

<a onclick="your_function(); return false;" href="/foo/bar">Foo Bar</a>
```

---

**Using [element.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)**

With default anchor behaviour following click:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("load", function() { 
        document.getElementById("your_link").addEventListener("click", function() {
            alert('clicked');
        }, true); 
    }, true);
</script> 

<a id="your_link" href="/foo/bar">Foo Bar</a>
```

Without:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("load", function() { 
        document.getElementById("your_link").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('clicked');
        }, true); 
    }, false);
</script> 

<a id="your_link" href="/foo/bar">Foo Bar</a>
```

Comment: `onclick` is olde-worlde DOM0 stuff - better yet, remove the JS code from your elements and add it on the fly with JS itself using `element.addEventListener()`

Comment: `element.addEventListener()` is less intuitive for the novice. First get them coding javascript, then get them learning more involved techniques.

Comment: @Michael OMG no! The last thing we should do is encourage novices to learn obsolete techniques.  Therein lies the route to a generation of "programmers" that thinks w3schools.com is the JS bible.

Comment: @Alnitak w3schools is not the JS bible?

Comment: @Michael just in case you're being serious, see w3fools.com

Comment: @Alnitak, I'm not being serious. But thanks for reminding me of that fountain of truth :) Why don't you post an answer using `element.addEventListener()` for the asker's reference?

Comment: @Michael for completeness I would like to see your answer, thanks.

Comment: @Michael done - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271598/create-a-dual-function-html-url-link/6271819#6271819

Answer (score 2):

Given current HTML and W3C APIs, I would go for:

```
<script src="linkify.js"> </script>
```

in the markup, with `linkify.js` containing something like:

```
window.onload= function() {
    document.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var el = ev.target;
        if (el.tagName === 'A') {
            // do stuff with el.href
        }
    }, false);
};
```

See e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/nrC7G/, or http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/6necb/ for a version which doesn't use `window.onload`.

Note that this code uses a *single* listener function registered on the `document` object, which will act on *every* `<A>` tag on the page that doesn't trap clicks for itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `onclick` attribute:

```
<a href="/home.html" onclick="javascript: performFunction(this); return false;">click?</a>
```

The `return false` prevents the default behaviour, in the absence of JavaScript, however, the link will be followed.

Answer (score 1):

```
function do_whatever (e)
{
   e.preventDefault ();

   // do whatever you want with e.target
}

var links = document.getElementsByTagName ("a");

for (var i=0; i<links.length; ++i)
   links[i].addEventListener ('click', do_whatever);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bTuN7/

All done inside script and it won't 'hurt' if JavaScript doesn't work.

If you think about AJAX, then you have to know, that googlebot tries to parse it. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qGGBYd51Ts

Answer (score 0):

You can code like:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    doSomethingWithURL($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```

JavaScript is not executed in case it's disabled or if it's some web crawler, so from my point of view this is preferable.

Comment: @David Thomas: jQuery is basically JavaScript, I don't see why not to use it here.

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript, yes; but [JavaScript is *not* jQuery (link to meta question)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91519/does-javascript-and-jquery-mean-the-same-thing/91527#91527). Some people don't want to import a library just for a click-handler (this is a personal choice, of the one asking the question). I, personally, prefer to use the jQuery library, for the abstractions if nothing else. The OP, however, didn't mention that he wanted to do so.

Comment: @David Thomas: That's correct - I'm sorry. I'm just not keen on the idea of adding handlers through HTML.

Comment: indeed, there's no need for _any_ JS to appear in the markup these days, other than `<script>` tags. That doesn't mean it _has_ to be jQuery though, much as I like it myself.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few methods out there such as this:
http://www.malbecmedia.com/blog/development/coding-a-ajax-site-that-degrades-gracefully-with-jquery/

Remember, though, that by virtue of a well setup server and caching you're not going to gain yourself much performance with an Ajax Load.